# Accessing Azure Mobile Service on Windows Phone from Different Projects

Tags: c#, silverlight, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

Hello I am having the following exception:

> Additional information: The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)

I did not understand why since the function worked sometimes I therefore found the following on stackoverflow:
[MobileServiceInvalidOperationException When Trying To Retrieve Data From Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909922/mobileserviceinvalidoperationexception-when-trying-to-retrieve-data-from-azure).
This issue unfortunately does not solve my issue.

The time is correct and I am using https connection. And all the communication is working perfectly. I however have divided my Windows Phone Silverlight application into several projects, the reason for this I have stated in another stackoverflow question: [Deleting project/pages/usercontrols from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914292/deleting-project-pages-usercontrols-from-memory).

The application flow is:

- Project 1:

  1. Login (Authenticate the mobileservice)
  2. Navigate to Mainmenu, upon success.
  3. Service is contacted `await MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<DTO.UserInfoDTO, DTO.UserInfoDTO>(UserInfoDTO);` Success **ALLWAYS!**
  4. MobileService saved to resources `Application.Current.Resources.Add("NavigationParam", App.MobileService);` and Navigating to new project is done.
- Project 2:

  1. Navigation parameter retrieved `MobileService = MobileServiceClient)Application.Current.Resources["NavigationParam"];` (information seems intact when looking into the debugger).
  2. Service is contacted `await MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<DTO.UserInfoDTO, DTO.UserInfoDTO>(UserInfoDTO);` Success **NEVER!**

I know the packages are in order in Project 2 because I can upload information to blob storage and the includes are the same in both projects. But as soon as I contact my own backend service the application crashes with the above exception.

So can anyone help me with this issue, do I need to create a new mobileserviceclient and reauthenticate? Seems stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is going wrong, but generally, I would recommend making a new client instance here.

To avoid a login issue I would look at caching the mobile service's token. (See: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#caching)

Then you can spin up a new client, reuse your existing auth tokens/etc, and continue on.